# Check if a join has already been done

Tags: mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm using Eloquent Scopes to decouple a big mysql query.

One of my scopes does a join between site and spot (site has many spots)

```
public function scopeWithSpots($query)
{
    return $query->join('spot', 'spot.site_id', '=', 'site.id');
}
```

And then other scopes (like the following) adds where conditions on spot table

```
public function scopeHasActiveSpots($query)
{
    return $query->where('spot.is_active', '>', 0);
}
```

Instead of doing the join in a separate scope, I want to be able to check inside `scopeHasActiveSpots()` if a join has already been made and if not create it, so I only do the join if needed.

Does it make sense ? Is there a way to do this with Eloquent ?

Comment: You can use this and just let it do the job for you: https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence/wiki/Builder-searchable-and-more#joining-relations Otherwise simply check its source https://github.com/jarektkaczyk/eloquence/blob/5.2/src/Relations/Joiner.php

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Indeed, the link you sent me has an alreadyJoined() that checks if the table is already joined. I'll be checking this out for sure. Thx.

Comment: Yeah, it's more than just this. That class over there automatically joins all (except for polymorphic, b/c that's impossible) relations without need to provide literally any data (table, keys etc).